# UIAutomator unable to launch the screen and showing an error message

Tags: android, appium

On opening UIAutomator and trying to inspect, the screen is not showing. It shows an error message as:

> Error obtaining UI hierarchy
>
> Reason: Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file.com.android.ddmlb.SynchException.Remote object doesn't exist.

Though my Appium server is stopped, then also showing same error message.
Please help me to inspect an element using UIAutomator

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

**1. Disconnect your device and reconnect it and take new screen shot using UIAutomator.**

OR

**2. Kill adb.exe from task manager and relaunch UIAutomator.**

This happens when you stop your appium script in middle and UIAutomator was in use and does not release the adb instance.